# How write Javascript for loading/writing contet from text-field from/to disk

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, io, hard-drive

how can I with a input text field with a button, let the user pick a .txt file from harddrive and also give the option of storing content from the text field onto harddrive, when using Chrome.

How can I do that with pure Javascript?

Kindest regards
/Lasse

Comment: You are unable to access file system from within client-side code due to [security reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Security). Unless you are talking about developing developing a Chrome plugin, but I don't see you mentioning this. You *could* give a shot to [File System API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_API) but it's supported very poorly and I'm unsure of it's capabilities since I've never used it.

Comment: OK, but I want to ask/give the user the choice to load from or save to disk, don't force the user. Can't I have a pop-up query?

Comment: You can load a text file using drag/drop or file input  but you can't save to it. You might want to look at localStorage where you can save data or use a server to handle storage

Comment: No, it is not a plugin, I am just a beginner writing an exam, and want to add an extra feature. No plugin, just ordinary webpage..

Comment: @Lasse Karagiannis See updated comment. But to my knowledge, this is one of the major security issues and it's highly unlikely that it will ever be implemented in such a manner. The best you could do is ask user to upload a file to your server and offer them to download resulting file. But you will not be able to open and write to file like you can from C, Java or similar.

Comment: MarkoGrešak  thank you I'll have a look!
@charlietfl, do you have a pointer to an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `input type="file"` with `accepts` MIME type set to `"text/plain"`, `textarea` , `a` element , `download` attribute , `FileReader` , `data:` protocol , `encodeURIComponent`

```js
var input = document.querySelector("input");
var text = document.querySelector("textarea");
var button = document.querySelector("button");
var name;

input.onchange = function() {
  name = this.files[0].name;
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    text.value = this.result
  }
  reader.readAsText(this.files[0])
}

button.onclick = function() {
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  // `"data:text/plain," + text.value` : new file
  a.href = "data:text/plain;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(text.value);
  a.download = name ||  "file-" + new Date().getTime();
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  // creates `"Save file"` dialog
  a.click();
  document.body.removeChild(a)
}
```

```html
<input type="file" accepts="text/plain"/><br>
<textarea width="300px" height="200px">
</textarea><br>
<button>save</button>
```

Comment: I love it!
Could you also explain how these rows work?
     `a.href = "data:text/plain;charset=utf-8," +     encodeURIComponent(text.value);
  a.download = name ||  "file-" + new Date().getTime();
  document.body.appendChild(a);`
  // creates `"Save file"` dialog
 ` a.click();
  document.body.removeChild(a)`

Comment: @LasseKaragiannis See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader ,  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Answer (score 1):

A full answer to your question would be very lengthy, so briefly:

Use a form with an input that is type file that allows the user to input a file:

```
<form>Select file: <input type="file" id="loadfile"/></form>
```

Using javascript, react to the value being set by listening to either the submit event, the click event, or the change event. The example here looks at the change event.

```
var input = document.getElementById('loadfile');
input.onchange = function handleInputFileChanged(event) {
  var files = event.target.files;
  if(!files || !files.length) {
    return;
  }
  importFiles(files);
};

function importFiles(files) {
  // Read in the contents of the files as text and process them here

  var numFiles = files.length;
  var filesProcessed = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < numFiles; i++) {
    processFile(files[i]);
  }

  function processFile(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
      filesProcessed++;

      // do something with the file text, here i am just printing 
      // it to the browser console
      var contentString = reader.result;
      console.log('File text: %s', contentString);

      if(filesProcessed === numFiles) allFilesRead();
    };
    reader.onerror = function() {
      filesProcessed++;
      if(filesProcessed === numFiles) allFilesRead();
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
  }

  function allFilesRead() {
    // do something now that all files have been read
  }
}
```

To save to a file, this can be done simply by providing the user a prompt. For example:

```
<form><button id="savebutton" value="Save"></form>
```

In script, listen for the button click event, and then initiate a download:

```
var button = document.getElementById('savebutton');
button.onclick = function(event) {
  var content = getContentToSaveAsString();


  // to automatically start a download, we are going to create a 
  // hidden anchor element, then pseudo-click it

  // Create the anchor and sets its href to a data uri
  var anchor = document.createElement('a');
  var blob = new Blob([content], {type: 'text/plain'});
  var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  anchor.href = objectURL;
  anchor.setAttribute('download', 'defaultfilenamegoeshere.txt');

  // attach the hidden anchor to the page
  anchor.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(anchor);

  // this starts the download, the user will get a prompt of where to 
  // save or if in chrome it just starts downloading to download 
  // folder, just as if they had right clicked on an anchor in 
  // the page and selected Save Target As
  anchor.click();

  // remove our temporary anchor element, cleaning up after ourselves
  URL.revokeObjectURL(objectURL);
  anchor.remove();
};

function getContentToSaveAsString() {
  // Create and return a string here that will be saved to a
  // text file when the user clicks the save button
  return 'string of stuff';
}
```